# backspace in vi editor in ubuntu12.04.2 LTS doesn't work

Tags: vi

As we know that vi editor has three modes namely: command mode,input mode & ex mode.By default,we get the command mode when the editor is evoked. Also we can navigate to other modes by using suitable commands like "i",":" etc. My problem is that when I press backspace in input mode,it doesn't erase the character unlike in the same editor that I have worked in RedHat does. I want to be clear about it.

Comment: Do you see **-- INSERT --**, when you press `i` in vi?

Comment: @Jobin ooo,I didn't mind it.Once I go and see it in the LAB,I will tell you as I am a teacher in a college, anyway thanks for your response.

Comment: If there isn't, you need to install vim using `sudo apt-get install vim`

Comment: @Jobin thanks again,but it requires internet connection,right? is there any way to do the same offline?

Comment: I am not aware of a method that can accomplish that, may be post a question regrading this(?)

Comment: @Jobin ofcourse,if any i will do (!)